# Socket.IO with multipul tabs of browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat

I am using socket.io in my node.js application to give real time experience to my users. But due to leak of my experience with socket.io, I have some doubt with browser tab management. Let me explain first.

My website does not allowed login to user from multipul browser at a time. means If someone login from one browser, and then try to login from another browser, I have to kill previous login session. Means my socket.io emit messages to previous browser's all tab for logout, but my second browser's all tab should not get message for logout. How Do I do this?

Another question is I want to count distinct logged in users for my deshboard. But with multipul tabs, count is showing wrong figger. (eg. Single user accessing website from single browser but from 2 or more tabs, on server, socket client is showing each connection for tab, Here I need just one count. How Do I get it?

If some one has example/sample regarding above user case, please share it, so new coumer will gets help from it.

thanks

Comment: You could try and distinct users by ip and count the numbers of double ip's. Would not really work in a internet cafe or people at home that use the website at same time.